# HTML/CSS Layouting 3 Div's Side by Side (left/center/right) using inline-block

Tags: html, css, layout

im searching for the best possible solution in weblayouting.
by having 3 divs inside one for the whole site (pagewrapper) in center.
the div1 should be on the left, div2 in the middle and div3 at the right side. the div in the middle should be bigger than those on the side.

i always used float but im not happy with this solution anymore

```css
 margin: 5px;
}

div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}

#parent {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.l {
 display: inline-block;
}

.m {
 display: inline-block;
}

.r {
 display: inline-block;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> -->
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="parent">
   <div class="l">1</div>
   <div class="m">2</div>
   <div class="r">3</div>
  </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

so this is what i got at the moment..

greetings mike

Comment: Your code seems to work.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: from now on i will use css: display: inline-block; http://www.yamii.ch/